# Chrome has old cache even when filename hash / fingerprint has been updated

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

We use Webpack filename hashes (ex. fqa_page.185e7e160a467e135f26.js) so that when a new js file is deployed, it has a new hash and the browser certainly won't cache it. We've been using this system for years, until about a month ago both internal personnel and users through support requests have started complaining about very strange issues that can only be explained as their cache being out of date.

I sat down today with one of these folks, got them to open Chrome DevTools and was shocked that:

1. The "Network" tab in Chrome DevTools shows them downloading the correct version.
2. Even crazier, when we checked "Disable Cache" on the Network tab and reloaded the page, it didn't help. The old page was being rendered.
3. When we inspect the page ("Elements" tab) we see the script tag with the correct file hash.
4. Back on the "Network" tab, I had them "Save As" on the response of one of hashed js files and it was exactly the same as mine (which displays correctly).

Astonishingly, only after step 4 (Save As) did the browser (on refresh) show the correct page.

Has anybody else seen anything like this? I can't imagine what could cause this.

Comment: FWIW, I think the latest version of Chrome fixed this. The issue just "went away".